# Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia GPU - Add virtual display

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg, remote-desktop, xrandr

I have a PC with an Nvidia GPU and one physical screen.

I'd like to be able to access my PC remotely with [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1) software from a client with two displays. I think I can achieve this by adding a virtual display beside my physical display using `xrandr`.

I tried everything I found on the internet, like:

- http://www.bictor.com/2017/08/15/installing-a-dummy-monitor/
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180904

but I never managed to create a new virtual display, add a definition on it and enable it.

My configuration: GTX 970 with latest Nvidia drivers (430.26) on Ubuntu 18.04.3.

If you have any clue...

Comment: Same problem here, everytime I create a xorg.conf or a file in xorg.conf.d, by any method I found, X server won't start